# How to write a Linq to entity statement, using sql not in operator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“NOT IN” clause in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432954/not-in-clause-in-linq-to-entities)

I work with the schema below, and I want to know how I can write in the sql query in LINQ to Entities.

SQL Code:

```
Select * 
FROM GROUEPUSERS G
WHERE G.IDGROUPE NOT IN (SELECT IDGROUPE
                         FROM  APPARTENIR
                         WHERE IDCLIENT = id)
```

The ID is a variable that I will recover. The problem is that the table APPARTENIR becomes a navigation table.

[image: x]

I found the solution just in case :

```
var groups = from g in context.GROUPEUSER 
    where !g.UTILISATEUR.Select(d => d.ID).Contains(id)
    select g;
```

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432954/not-in-clause-in-linq-to-entities**

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answers
but i'm just a beginner with entity framework and i don't know how i can deal with it yet, i'm reading some tutorials and i progress but here i need some help,

Comment: Where is your APPARTENIR entity in your screenshot? I don't see which columns and tables map to which entities and properties in your screenshot.

Comment: That's the problem when i generated the entities it didn't give me an entity named APPARTENIR that contain the primary key of UTILISATEUR and GROUPEUSER it just transform it to NAVIGATION PROPERTY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like that:

```
 var query = myEntities.Groupeusers
     .Where(gu => !myEntities.Utilisateur.Any(ut => ut.idgroupe == gu.idgroupe)).ToList();
```

That should work.

**EDIT:**

Try that query instead:

```
 var query = myEntities.Groupeusers
     .Where(gu => !myEntities.Utilisateur
                .SelectMany(ut=>ut.Groupeuser)
                .Any(gu => gu.Idgroupe == gu.Idgroupe)).ToList();
```

OR maybe even better:

```
 var query = myEntities.GroupeUsers
     .Except(myEntities.Utilisateur.SelectMany(ut => ut.Groupeuser))
     .ToList();
```

**EDIT2:**

If I understand your query correct, you would like to identify a special user entity.

```
var query = myEntities.GroupeUsers 
     .Except(myEntities.Utilisateur.Where(u => u.IdUser == id).SelectMany(ut => ut.Groupeuser)) 
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you BitKFu
But i can't get IDGROUP from entity UTILISATEUR it just gave me ut.GROUPEUSERS and not the attribut IDGROUPE

Comment: I think the problem is, that you did not map the link table APPARTENIR in your entity model. That's really the missing link in here.

Comment: Do you have a tutoriel or course that can help me to understand more , because all of tutorials that i had read aren't spécific.
Any way thanks for your HELP :)

Comment: AND the ID variable that I recover where should i put it 
PS : i used the seconde query  : 
`var query = myEntities.GroupeUsers
     .Except(myEntities.Utilisateur.SelectMany(ut => ut.Groupeuser))
     .ToList();`
@BitKFu