# Entity Framework exclude result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity

I would like to exlude a query result.

E.g I have:

```
Table_1 (Id, name)
Table_2 (Id, Table_1_Id)
```

And, I want to write query which return only the result from `Table_1` which does not exist in `Table_2`. It is a relation of **one to many**.

Any ideas ?

```
var query = db.Table_1.Include("Table_2").Where(????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Except`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432954/not-in-clause-in-linq-to-entities):

```
var query = db.Table_1.Select(MapToType).Except(db.Table_2.Select(MapToSameType));
```

If you're using an old version of EF that does not support it, you can use `All`:

```
var query = db.Table_1.Where(x => db.Table_2.All(y => y.Table_1_Id != x.Id);
```