# Using 'NOT IN' Clause in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have tested the following LINQ query in LINQPad. But it gives me this error:

> Error Compiling Expression: Error Compiling Expression: The best overloaded method match for 'string.Contains(string)' has some invalid arguments
>   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'

```
(from t in db.ASN_ITEM
join t0 in db.ASN_MASTER on t.AWB_NO equals t0.AWB_NO
join t1 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t1.ITEM_CODE
where
  (t.TOT_QTY - t.SCND_QTY) != 0 &&
  !t.AWB_NO.Contains((from t2 in db.ASN_ITEM
                    where
                     t2.SCAN_STAT != 2
                        select new {
                         t2.AWB_NO
                        }).Distinct()) &&
  t.AWB_NO == "E1000001"
select new {
  t.AWB_NO,
  ASN_DATE = t.REC_DATE,
  t.PALLET,
  t.CARTON,
  t.TOT_QTY,
  t.SCND_QTY,
  VAR_QTY = (System.Int32?)(t.SCND_QTY - t.TOT_QTY),
  REMARKS = 
  (t.TOT_QTY - t.SCND_QTY) == 0 ? "No Variance" : 
  (t.TOT_QTY - t.SCND_QTY) > 0 ? "Less Qty" : 
  (t.TOT_QTY - t.SCND_QTY) < 0 &&
  t.TOT_QTY != 0 ? "Excess Qty" : 
  t.TOT_QTY == 0 &&
  t.SCND_QTY != 0 ? "Excess Item" : null,
  t1.PART_NO
}).Distinct()
```

I got this error, when I give below condition in where clause:

```
!t.AWB_NO.Contains((from t2 in db.ASN_ITEM
                where
                 t2.SCAN_STAT != 2
                    select new {
                     t2.AWB_NO
                    }).Distinct())
```

Actually in SQL query, this is what I needed (below):

```
WHERE ASN_ITEM.AWB_NO NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT AWB_NO FROM ASN_ITEM WHERE SCAN_STAT !=2 )
```

Comment: I think it's because your `select new { ... }` inside `Contains(...)` creates a new anonymous type. You'll have to parse it to string or create `new string {...}`.

Comment: Assuming `t2.AWB_NO` is a string you can just use `select t2.AWB_NO` instead of using projection with the `new` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should've done it the other way around. Call `Contains()` on the subquery, the one that has multiple items in it :

```
!(from t2 in db.ASN_ITEM
  where t2.SCAN_STAT != 2
  select t2.AWB_NO
).Distinct()
 .Contains(t.AWB_NO)
```

Also, you have to select `AWB_NO` directly, as shown above, instead of projecting to anonymous type. Doing the latter will prevent usage of `Contains()`, since item type in collection will be different from object type passed as parameter of `Contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I gather that `AWB_NO` is a string. If so, then what you're doing here:

```
!t.AWB_NO.Contains((from t2 in db.ASN_ITEM
                where
                 t2.SCAN_STAT != 2
                    select new {
                     t2.AWB_NO
                    }).Distinct())
```

translates to this: "It's not true that a **string** `ABW_NO` contains (and it's [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) `Contains`, not [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx)) a table of some distinct elements of anonymous type with one string property". Which makes no sense. It isn't a "not in" query. You're checking if a single String contains a set of anonymous type objects.

if you want to use a `String.Contains` and check if a string contains another string, then this will make more sense (may be not what you want though):

```
!t.AWB_NO.Contains((from t2 in db.ASN_ITEM
                where
                 t2.SCAN_STAT != 2
                    select t2.AWB_NO).FirstOrDefault())
```

You may find this helpful:

[How would you do a "not in" query with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

["NOT IN" clause in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432954/not-in-clause-in-linq-to-entities)